# Passing array with fork exec

Tags: c, arrays, pipe, fork, exec

I need to implement a scheduler simulator. 
I have a main process and a child process. The main reads a joblist from a file and then passes it to the child which is the scheduler.

I want the scheduler to run as a separated file using the execvp function.
I have problems to pass the array created with `malloc` and `realloc` from the main to the scheduler. I tried using a pipe but I don't know if it works because I don't know how to access to the array when I code the scheduler as a separated file. I tried using the same name for the array but obviously when trying to compile it says the array is not declared.

Is the pipe the right solution in this case or is it possible to pass an array as an argument calling the exec function?

And how can I "declare" the array while coding the scheduler in a separate file?

Comment: Why does the parent process read and pass the data to the child?  Why doesn't the child read the file?  Could the parent pass the file name to the child?  What is the type of the data in the array?  Do you need to serialize the data as it is written to the pipe (before it is written), and deserialize it in the child process?  Should you use shared memory?  How big is the data going to be?  How much does the size vary?  Is the data passed once during setup, or can it be refreshed several times while the child is running?

Comment: The specifics ask that the data needs to be red by the main process and passed to the child. The data are fictional jobs and their instruction with lenght and so on. Everything is stored in a text file. So i read the file and  store everything in an array of structs with int variables ( job id, instr lenghts..) to be passed to the child. Shared memory is an option if it is usable. Data must be passed 1 time than the parent just waits for the child to process everything( simulating the work of a scheduler). So no need to refresh data

Comment: If it's all one-off and mainly educational, then fine.  You can create an array of the structures, populated with the data from the file, and then write that to the child (simulator) process, and then close the pipe.  You don't need to supply a length since the structures are all fixed size and there are no pointers in the data (rules change if this interpretation of your comments are incorrect).  The child reads until EOF (zero bytes read).  It processes; it reports; it dies; the parent wakes and collects the death certificate and continues on its merry way.

Comment: Can you please post how an array is written to the child and then red from the child cause i'm having troubles doing that.Thanks for the fast answers!

Comment: No; you've not shown your code attempting to do it, nor the details of the structure.  I'll help you fix an honest attempt at solving your problem; I won't just solve the problem without you showing your code.  You should check on the rules for creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  For pipes, you usually use `read()` and `write()` system calls, rather than `fread()` and `fwrite()`.